# Problema ao imprimir matriz c++

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos

Estou tentando ler uma matriz e imprimí-la completamente, porém só está saindo a última linha e não sei o motivo.

```
#include "matriz.hpp"
#include <iostream>

Matriz::Matriz(){
  char matriz[0][0];
  int quantidade_linhas=0 ;
  int quantidade_colunas=0 ;
}

int Matriz::getLinhas(){
  return quantidade_linhas;
}

void Matriz::insere_Linhas(){
  cout << "Digite a quantidade de linhas desejadas: ";
  cin >> quantidade_linhas;
  this -> quantidade_linhas= quantidade_linhas;
}

int Matriz::getColunas(){
  return quantidade_colunas;
}

void Matriz::insere_Colunas(){
  cout << "Digite a quantidade de colunas desejadas: ";
  cin >> quantidade_colunas;
  this -> quantidade_colunas = quantidade_colunas;
}

void Matriz::cria_Matriz(){
  matriz [quantidade_linhas][quantidade_colunas];
  }

void Matriz::imprime_matriz(){
  int linhas = getLinhas();
  int colunas = getColunas();

  for(int i=0 ; i<linhas ; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<colunas ; j++){
      cin >> matriz[i][j] ;
    }
  }

  for(int i=0 ; i<linhas ; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<colunas ; j++){
      cout << matriz[i][j] ;
    }
  }

}
```

É apenas o aquivo fonte "matriz.cpp". A definição da classe e a função `main` não se encontram aí, se necessário eu posto o link com eles também.

edit: Como foi pedido o "matriz.hpp" aqui está

```
#ifndef MATRIZ_HPP
#define MATRIZ_HPP

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Matriz{

private:
char matriz[0][0];
int quantidade_linhas;
int quantidade_colunas;
int geracoes;
bool cel_viva;
bool cel_morta;


public:
Matriz();

void insere_Linhas();
int  getLinhas();
void insere_Colunas();
int getColunas();
void cria_Matriz();
void imprime_matriz();

};
#endif
```

Comment: Favor colocar o "matriz.hpp" para que saibamos os campos que foram definidos e seus tipos. Já adianto que o construtor aparenta ter problemas, pois ele declara variáveis locais e as inicializa ao invés de atribuir os valores aos campos.

Comment: Ja atualizei o post com o matriz.hpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como comentado, você criou campos na estrutura mas não atribuiu valores no construtor. Quando você define algo no construtor, você define variável local (como em qualquer função ou método), portanto não está inicializando os campos mas sim variáveis locais do construtor.

Simplificadamente, o certo seria isso.

```
Matriz::Matriz(){
  //char matriz[0][0] ;
  quantidade_linhas = 0 ;
  quantidade_colunas = 0 ;
}
```

Além disso, você criou uma matriz 0x0 e não dá para modificar o tamanho. Para fazer uma matriz de tamanho especificável, você tem duas opções: template ou ponteiro. Definindo a classe com templates, você poderá criar tipos de matrizes com tamanhos pré-determinados (por exemplo, `Matriz<3,2>` é matriz de duas linhas e três colunas, não poderá mudar). Com ponteiros, sempre que for determinar o tamanho da matriz você aloca células que suportem esse tamanho.

Isso já resolve boa parte dos problemas, não sei se resolve todos de modo que o programa funcione. Se tiver mais problemas ou alguma dúvida, favor informar.